# Trying to implement pagination in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Here I am trying to achieve a pagination in vue.js. To achieve that I have written vue.js script and also template. So here pagination is not working in my case I have tried alot but unable to understand where I am going wrong. I have implemented this in JavaScript and it was working fine but I am trying to implement in vue. So if anyone can have an ide please help me

```
<body translate="no" >
  <div id="app" class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="offset">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="msglist_header">
            <th>Member</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody id="inbox-1">
        {% if displayedPosts%}
        {% for i in displayedPosts%}
        <tr class="content_set">
                <div>
                    <a class="fix">{{i.username|first|upper}}
                        <span>{{i.username|last|upper}}</span></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a>
                    <div class="show-form-msgrply a">
                        {{i.ttle}}
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a>
                    <div id="classi_msg">{{i.message}}</div>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="f">
                    {% for key,value in some_date.items %}
                    {% if i.id == key %}
                    <a>{{ value }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="show-form-msg-delete">
                    <a>
                        <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                    </a>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </tbody>
  </table>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item">
                    <button type="button" class="page-link" v-if="page != 1" @click="page--"> Previous </button>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <button type="button" class="page-link" v-for="pageNumber in pages.slice(page-1, page+5)" @click="page = pageNumber"> {{pageNumber}} </button>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <button type="button" @click="page++" v-if="page < pages.length" class="page-link"> Next </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [''],
      page: 1,
      perPage: 4,
      pages: [] };

  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      let data = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
        this.posts.push(data);
      }window.CP.exitedLoop(0);
    },
    setPages() {
      let numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.posts.length / this.perPage);
      for (let index = 1; index <= numberOfPages; index++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) break;
        this.pages.push(index);
      }window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
    },
    paginate(posts) {
      let page = this.page;
      let perPage = this.perPage;
      let from = page * perPage - perPage;
      let to = page * perPage;
      return posts.slice(from, to);
    } },

  computed: {
    displayedPosts() {
      return this.paginate(this.posts);
    } },

  watch: {
    posts() {
      this.setPages();
    } },

  created() {
    this.getPosts();
  },
  filters: {
    trimWords(value) {
      return value.split(" ").splice(0, 20).join(" ") + '...';
    } } });
```

Comment: Could you please describe what is working so far, what is not working and provide error messages if you get any. Otherwise it's hard for other people to help you.

Comment: @Luckyfella thanks for response. Actually in my case pagination itself is not working why because I am not able to bind the data with vue script so there I am doing some thing wrong. I am not able to access the data from template to vue.js script to display the data per page

Comment: You don't get any error messages? Just by looking at the code provided it's really hard to find something. You could check some tutorials like this one: https://bezkoder.com/vue-pagination-axios/

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all your `{% %}` code (what language is that used?) with Vue attributes, etc.  For example

```
 <tbody id="inbox-1">
    {% if displayedPosts%}
    {% for i in displayedPosts%}
    <tr class="content_set">
```

should be rewritten as

```
 <tbody id="inbox-1" v-if="displayPosts">
    <tr class="content_set" v-for="i in displayedPosts" :key="i.id">
```